# Direction of CMB and magnetic fields?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, cosmic-microwave-background

Measurements show the CMB is warmer to the North.

Could more photons coming from that direction of the sky, cause metals in the Earth to move in that particular direction?

As the Earth orbits the Sun and the Sun rotates (and has its own larger orbit around the the Galaxy), would that cause the metals to keep moving toward the northern hemisphere of our CMB?

Comment: Uhh, it's warmer in the [**southern** hemisphere](http://www.space.com/20330-cosmic-microwave-background-explained-infographic.html). Also, what do you mean by your first question (photons cause metals in earth to move in some direction)?

Comment: Do the teaspoons in your cupboard follow the orientation of the sun? Why not?

Comment: Ok, I know, ridiculous right. But photons are (go easy on me) energy in an electromagnetic field, so couldn't more electromagnetic radiation coming from one side of sky, given enough time, push or pull metals in the earth?